# Looping Through Cells in Worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing code in VBA for Excel to loop through all the cells in all the worksheets in a workbook and print certain cells based on their numeric value and position. However, I am unable to loop through the cells in a specific worksheet as I get a 424 object required error.

I have tried to debug my code and apparently the problems lies in my nested loop when I try to loop through the entire cells in a specific worksheet.

```
Public Sub loopThrougSheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning
Dim cell As Range
Dim data As Range

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Activate
Set data = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Range("A2:AW1048576"))
    For Each cell In data
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) And cell.Value > 0.5 Then
            Debug.Print (cell.Value)
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

The code does not compile as I get a 424 object required run time error.

Comment: On which line do you have this error?

Comment: Which line? Do you have an error values? I'd suggest first checking that cell is not an error and then doing your other checks (nested).

Comment: The error is on this line: For Each cell In data. The error I get is Run-time error: '424', Object required.

Comment: Probably because data returns nothing. Sheet could be blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below:**

**Reason:** Data was returning Nothing, sheet could be blank or there is nothing in the Intersection.

Added **IsError** Check for cell and if the Data is nothing.

```
Public Sub loopThrougSheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet

Dim cel As Range
Dim data As Range

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set data = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Range("A2:AW1048576"))
        If Not data Is Nothing Then
        For Each cel In data
            If Not IsError(cel.Value) Then
            If IsNumeric(cel.Value) And cel.Value > 0.5 Then
                Debug.Print cel.Value
            End If
            End If
        Next
        End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Out of curiosity why did the error arise in the first place?

Comment: Sheet was Blank, so your Data returned Nothing :) .. Accept the answer if it worked

Comment: Thank you. I can only accept this answer in 4 minutes. No idea Stack Overflow was this fast at answering questions :)

Comment: HaHa ... the People on StackOverFlow are :) Kudos to everyone.